# Disable blacken-mode on certain projects

Tags: python, formatting, directory-local-variables

I have `blacken-mode` enabled on all python buffers like this:

```lisp
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (blacken-mode 1)
            ;; other config
            ))
```

But on some existing projects, where `black` is not used, I don't want it on by default.  I would like to enable `blacken-mode` per buffer manually.

So I attempted to disable `blacken-mode` in a project by adding the following `.dir-locals.el`:

```lisp
((python-mode . ((blacken-mode . nil))))
```

However, the behaviour I get is strange.  When I open a Python file (after marking the directory local variables as safe), edit, and save. `black` still reformats it, however running <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `blacken-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> I get the message "Blacken mode enabled in current buffer". So I have to repeat <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`blacken-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd>, and then I get "Blacken mode disabled in current buffer", after that `black` does not reformat the buffer any more.

So the directory local variables are getting picked up, but it doesn't behave the way I'm expecting.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a variable is not enough to disable the mode: you have to call  the mode function with a negative argument. You can use the `eval` pseudo-variable for that:

```el
((python-mode . ((eval . (blacken-mode -1)))))
```

The setting of file-local (or directory-local) variables happens after the mode hook is run, so the mode turns on `blacken-mode`, but then we eval the expression above and turn it off again. See the function `run-mode-hooks` for the details of how that happens.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `run-mode-hooks` :)